# Retrieve links from an Access db with PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, odbc

i'm having an issue listing up the links I have in an access database.
I'm new to this so even if i searched thru' the answered questions I couldn't find anything to help me out. I have a search form that when you type, it automatically filters the table i'm accessing from the databse. But i get this error when i'm accessing the field where I have the links listed: "Notice: Undefined index: Título in C:\xampp\htdocs\buscar.php on line 21"
Bassically  what I have to do is a search form where you search in a category and all the pdfs related to that category would show up and should be clickable so you can read the one you're interested in.
The code I have is this, where **Ser_presenta** is the category and **Título** is where the url's are listed.
Index php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=es>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Protocolos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function buscarq() {
                var buscarTxt = $("input[name='Buscar']").val();
                $.get("buscar.php", {buscarVal: buscarTxt}, function(output){
                    $("#output").html(output);
                });
            }

        </script>
    <center>
        <h2> Protocolos Médicos </h2>
        <form action="protocolosphp.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="Buscar" placeholder="Buscar protocolos..." onkeyup="buscarq();" size="50"/>
            <input type="submit" value=">>" />

        </form>
        <div id="output"> 
        </div>
    </center>
    </body>

</html>
```

Php that should retrieve data from the databse:

```
<?php

    $conexion = odbc_connect ("ProtocolosIndex", "", "")
                or die ('No se pudo conectar a la base de datos'); 

    $output = '';

    //collect
    if(isset($_GET['buscarVal'])) {
        $buscarq = $_GET['buscarVal'];

        $query =  odbc_exec($conexion, "SELECT  * FROM  tblRegistros WHERE Ser_presenta LIKE '%$buscarq%';") or die ("No se ha podido buscar");

        $count = odbc_num_rows($query); 
            if($count == 0){
                $output = 'No se han encontrado resultados';
            }
            else {
                while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)){
                    $depart = $row['Ser_presenta'];
                    $titulo = $row['Título'];


                $output .= '<div>'  .$depart. '<br />' .'<a href="{$row->Ser_presenta}">$row->Título</a>'. '</div>';

                }
         }
}
echo ($output);?>
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: `print_r($row)`, what do you see?

Comment: When using print_r($row) it only shows the same and nothing else: "Notice: Undefined index: Título in C:\xampp\htdocs\buscar.php on line 21"

Comment: What __same__ does it shows?

Comment: What I wrote above in the quotes.                    This: Notice: Undefined index: Título in C:\xampp\htdocs\buscar.php on line 21.

Comment: It was an issue i had with the access db i was given to work with, because the db use a different encode type than utf8. I simply needed to change the field name from Título to Titulo without the accent on i.